# How to store reference to std::map object with different comparators?

Tags: c++, casting, stl, containers, polymorphism

I would like to create a variable that stores references to std::map objects. These map objects are of type `std::map<int, int, Cmp>` where Cmp could be **either** `std::greater<int>` **or** `std::less<int>`. How could I best achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: creating my own comparator is not an optimal option in my case because 1. I need to integrate with the rest of the code which uses std::greater and std::less and 2. because it's too slow.

Comment: Create a comparator with the same type but have a member doing the comparison in the way you want. That would slow things down somewhat tho...

Comment: You can't do exacly that since the types are unrelated. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for your reply. There are objects of class "A" which can be inserted into one of the two std::maps with std::greater or std::less. They can also switch between those. The objects of class A now need to hold a reference to the map they are inserted in.

Comment: I toesn't work like that. If you have to different compare operations you need to different instances of your mapping. You might do some tests to check if std::unordered_map is faster in your case (depends on hash function overhead). Also keeping references in a map is kind of fragile if the target objects are in another stl container that can reallocate.

Comment: So what are you trying todo, because I agree with molbdnilo. You show HOW you want to do something,  but you are not explaining WHAT you are trying todo. And it looks like you're setting yourself up for bugs.

Comment: Thanks.  To summarise again, objects of class A are inserted into one of two maps with different comparators. They can also switch between the maps. Each inserted object A should hold a reference to the map in which it was inserted. One approach I was thinking about was to store a void pointer to the map and cast it to the correct type when needed.

Comment: `std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>>` and `std::map<int, int, std::less<int>>` are different types, and so are references and pointers to those. C++ has `std::variant` for that (or plain `union` if you know what you are doing).

Comment: Why does a map need to use `greater`? Maybe you could instead iterate over a normal map backwards?

Comment: You are not describing the problem you're solving with the references. You are describing your solution.

Comment: @n.m. thanks std::variant seems promising. Do you know if it has a lot of overhead? I see some of the methods throw.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74744719/4117728 ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for the reply. It does answer the question somewhat. However, I already knew this solution and deemed it too inefficient. Thanks anyways.

Comment: the requirement to use `std::greater` / `std::less` for speed is moot. They are no faster than `<` or `>` or a selfwritten comparator. They are more generic, but for one case of keys that is irrelevant

Comment: your point about efficiency is unclear. If you have code that is too slow you should show that code.

Comment: A selfwritten comparator can be as fast, however only if it can't "change ordering dynamically" because in that case you have to check the "flipped" bool (see the link you posted)

Comment: you want to change the comparator at runtime, saying that changing the comparator at runtime is too unefficient is contradicting yourself. Nothing is for free.

Comment: No, I said that I want the reference to the map be dynamic. So rather than changing the map ordering dynamically, I change (e.g. cast) the reference.

Comment: `std::greater<int>` and `std::less<int>` can both be used as `bool (*)(const int&,const int&)`. Make that your type of the maps comparator, then create one map with `std::less` the other with `std::greater`. It is not clear why this does not meet your requirements.

Comment: "No, I said that I want the reference t... " but the type of the comparator is part of the maps type. If you want two maps of same type with different comparator then you need to select the comparator at runtime, when constructing the map

Comment: No there are other ways like std::variant

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number function objects are inlineable and function pointers are usually not, this makes a lot of difference (sometimes).

Comment: A variant of just a couple of pointers shouldn't throw in any of the usual implementations. If you are concerned, use a `union` of pointers (or a `void*`) with a discriminant, it can function as a very stripped-down `std::variant`.

Comment: @n.m. yeah I also realized this after starting to type something to see where the issue lies. I still think OP should clarify the question to explain what their issue is. The answer for the title is simple, what they actually want/need is not that clear.